# VUE failed to resolve component SVG when loaded with vite-svg-loader

Tags: vue.js, svg, vite

I am using **VUE 3** and **vite** for my project. I have installed `vite-svg-loader` and imported and included the svg file as below.

```
import ProgressPin1 from '../assets/svg/google.svg?components';

export default {
    components: {
        ProgressPin1
    }
}
```

Afterwards, I tried using the SVG inside my file as below:

```
<template>
    <ProgressPin1/>
</template>
```

However, I am still getting the following error in my `console`.

```
Failed to resolve component: ProgressPin1
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via
```

Do advise! Thank you.

Comment: try https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-svg-sfc

Comment: Installed and tried that, get the same error! I noticed that all the examples use `<script setup>` instead of just `<script>`, is there any difference besides having to go the extra step to declare the SVG as a `components` ?

Comment: can you upload error code to https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: This is my first time uploading to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-h76dfv?file=src/components/HelloWorld.vue). I am not sure where to include in the import statements that are present in my file under `vite.config.js` which I have included below. Will need some help linking the path too.

Comment: ```import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import svgSfc from "vite-plugin-svg-sfc";


// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue({
    template:{

    }
  }), svgSfc()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: emmmm, your stackblitz example is `vue-cli-service`, it is baseed webpack, not vite

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249100/discussion-between-peek0-and-lisonge).